# Length of a differentiable curve with respect to a Riemannian metric.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, arc-length

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold ($n\ge1$). A Riemannian metric in $X$ is a family $\{g_p\,|\,p\in X\}$, where for all $p\in X$:

- $g_p:T_pX\times T_pX\to\mathbb{R}$ is an inner product for all $p\in X$,
- and for every differentiable chart $(U,h,V)$ for $X$ at $p$ with coordinates $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in $V$, the map $g_{ij}:U\to\mathbb{R}, g_{ij}(p)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(p),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(p)\right)$ is differentiable for each $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ (here $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(p)\,1\le i\le n\right\}$ is a basis for $T_pX$).

A differentiable map $\gamma:[a,b]\to X$ is said to be differentiable curve if there exists some $\epsilon_\gamma>0$ and a differentiable curve $\tilde\gamma:(a-\epsilon_\gamma,b+\epsilon_\gamma)\to X$ such that $\tilde\gamma|_{[a,b]}=\gamma$.

I showed that a differentiable curve $\gamma$ defined on a closed interval defines a geometric tangent vector $[\gamma](t)\in T_pX$ for all $t\in[a,b]$; for $t\in(a,b)$ this is nearly trivial, and for $t\in\{a,b\}$ I used the differentiable extension and the fact that the left and right limits coincide, to show that the value of the derivative of the constructed curve is determined by $\gamma$, i.e.
\begin{align}
[\gamma](t)=\begin{cases}
[\mu_t^\epsilon],\quad\text{if }t\in(a,b), \\
[\tilde\mu_t^\epsilon],\quad\text{if }t\in\{a,b\},
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\epsilon\in(0,\epsilon_\gamma)$, $\mu_t^\epsilon=\gamma\circ\iota_t^\epsilon\circ T_t^\epsilon$, and $\tilde\mu_t^\epsilon=\tilde\gamma\circ\iota_t^\epsilon\circ T^\epsilon_t$; here $T_t^\epsilon:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)$ is the translation and $\iota_t^\epsilon:(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)\to(a-\epsilon_\gamma,b+\epsilon_\gamma)$ is the inclusion.

I now have to show that the length
\begin{align}
L(\gamma)=\int_a^b\sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}([\gamma](t),[\gamma](t)}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
satisfies the property $L(\gamma)=L(\gamma\circ f)$, where $f:[c,d]\to[a,b]$ is some diffeomorphism. Of course this comes down to the substitution rule for integrals, as the derivative of $f$ comes out of the square root. For $t'\in(c,d)$ you can also write down this down explicitly, since, letting $[\alpha_{t'}^\epsilon]$ be the geometric tangent vector defined by $\gamma\circ f$, we have for any chart $(U,h,v)$ at $h(\gamma(f(t'))$ (by the chain rule)
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(h\circ\alpha_t^\epsilon)(0)&=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{(h\circ\gamma\circ f)(t'+k)-(h\circ\gamma\circ f)(t')}{k} \\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(h\circ\gamma\circ f)(t') \\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(h\circ\gamma)(f(t'))\cdot Df(t').
\end{align}
Now $Df(t')>0$ or $Df(t')<0$ for all $t'\in(c,d)$, so this comes out nicely out of the square root. For $t'\in\{c,d\}$ though, I'm somewhat puzzled. You use the differentiable extension $\hat{\gamma}$ of $\gamma\circ f$ to define $\alpha_{t'}^\epsilon$, and the value of derivative at zero of $h\circ\alpha_{t'}^\epsilon$ is (by the right and left limit coinciding argument) determined by $\gamma\circ f$, but here we cannot write down $Df(t')$ as before, since it is only the right (or left) limit!

Now my first thought was: Ah, I know measure theory, and those boundary points constitute a set of measure zero, so that doesn't count anyway. However even if this thought can be formalized, I would like to know if there is a formal way out of this that sticks to just using the chain rule and the things given/already done. Any help/thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not certain, but perhaps there's an argument that any diffeomorphism $f: [c, d] \to [a, b]$ extends to a diffeomorphism $F: [c', d'] \to [a', b']$, where $c' < c < d < d'$, and similarly for the codomain. If so, then the derivative of $F$ equals that of $f$ on $(c, d)$, and matches the left and right derivatives at $c'$ and $d'$, and then you're good to go.

Comment: I certainly thought of this (well for some open $(c',d')$), but then what happens is that...ah! I didn't think this through enough. What happens is that for the boundary points the derivative of this extension comes out, and this value is determined by $f$ itself. But still, you can't write $(\gamma\circ)(t)$ for $t\in\{c,d\}$ to be able to cleanly use the substitution rule. Perhaps you could define $d/dt(h\circ\gamma\circ f)(t)$ as the right (left) limit? There is also the question of how the extensions of $\gamma\circ f$ and $f$ relate, but that can be solved I think.

Comment: You don't need measure theory to prove that if $F = G$ on $(c, d)$, then $\int_c^t F(t)  dt = \int_c^d G(t) dt$, and that's really the only lemma that you need to make your argument work.

Comment: You are certainly right. So essentially, we extend the integral to some larger domain, argue the invariance under the diffeomorphism with the extensions, and then this holds for the original domain. Right? That sounds nice.

Comment: @JohnHughes To your first comment, consider a differentiable homeorphism $f:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ such that $f'$ limits to zero at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Neal: you're thinking, perhaps, of a map like $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]: x \mapsto x^3$. The problem is that the inverse of this map isn't smooth at $0$, so I'd say it's not a diffeomorphism (but opinions and definitions may vary).